# Truncated CEF of normally distributed RV. Is sample analogue a consistent estimator of the 'population' truncated CEF?

Tags: random-variable, population, consistency, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

If I have a random variable that is normally distributed, and truncated such that I only see $y$ if $y\geq 0$,
and I want to do some calculations with the truncated Conditional Expectation Function in my sample, where it equals 
$$E[y|y\geq0]= \mu + \sigma\lambda(0,\mu,\sigma)$$ 
where $\mu$ is the mean, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, and $\lambda$ is the [inverse Mills Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio#Inverse_Mills_ratio), is the sample analogue of this that could be calculated in any statistical software a consistent estimator of the population CEF? or is it just informative only about the sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When truncating a Normal sample to its positive part, one generates a sample from the truncated Normal distribution (by a direct accept-reject argument). Hence the empirical mean for that truncated sample is a converging estimator of the population mean of the corresponding truncated Normal distribution.